# Communication between controller fail on page reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I have been using the below reference for sharing the $scope between the controllers. I use Controller1 in xxx.html and Controller2 in yyy.html.

This worked fine until one thing have happened. When I reloaded the page, the service could not read the previous controller's $scope. This could be used for the controller's in a single page, but for my case I have different pages for Controller1 and Controller2.

Can any one give me a solution to overcome this?

[Reference](http://jsfiddle.net/gonzalo123/myc5rcLw/)

Service:

```
app.factory('Scopes', function ($rootScope) {
    var mem = {};

    return {
        store: function (key, value) {
            $rootScope.$emit('scope.stored', key);
            mem[key] = value;
        },
        get: function (key) {
            return mem[key];
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This could lead you more work here.

1 : the very first thing if you are reloading page ( browser reload ) you are using angular wrong way .

2 :  always  angular should be single page application.

3 : here what you need is  sharing data after $state change (may be) if you are using $state routes it will not reload but it will change pages and urls.

4: in 3rd case you need to store your data in $rootScope or $parent $scope and then you can use it in any next or previous controllers.

5:  there are  3 recommended ways to share data with controllers 
  Services
  Events 
  RootScope

I recommend your using service or  Events if you need more help let me know.